# WP_Query order by taxonomy (product categories) and alphabetically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, sql-order-by, taxonomy

I have a search filter on a custom page. In it, I define the arrays of arguments depending on what type of search I am doing, either a search by category, by taxonomy or by custom fields.
What I need is for the results of this page to be displayed first by product category, and then alphabetically. I have searched the documentation but cannot find the proper way to use `order_by` for taxonomies.

This is some of the code Im using, so you get the idea:

```
    $metaQueryArray = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'referencia',
            'value'     => $reference,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
    );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 9,
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'paged'             => $paged,
    'tax_query'         => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
    ),
);
```

I edit the arguments according to the type of search I am doing

```
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

How can I achieve this?